# Decompile .dll files without .net reflector

Tags: installed-programs

How do I decompile a .dll file without .net reflector, I don't use it because it doesn't work.
Can somebody suggest me some programs?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have downloaded the .NET Reflector & this [FileGenerator plugin](http://filegenreflector.codeplex.com/) , If you do,

- Open up the Reflector.exe,
- Go to View and click Add-Ins,
- In the Add-Ins window click Add..,
- Then find the dll you have downloaded FileGenerator.dll (which came with the FileGenerator plugin),
- Then close the Add-Ins window.
- Go to File and click Open and choose the dll that you want to decompile,
- After you have opened it, it will appear in the tree view,
- Go to Tools and click Generate Files (Ctrl+Shift+G),
- select the output directory and select appropriate settings as your wish,
- Click generate files.

Comment: When i open the ReflectorInstaller it pops up a windows with .net reflector then it closes

Answer (score 0):

You can try Ilspy decompiler for .net executables. So far I can remember it gave me quite good output.

You can use Playonlinux - third party wine wrapper for this:

1. Download and install Playonlinux and winbind with 
   `apt-get install playonlinux winbind`. Download Ilspy binaries from ilspy.net.
2. Run Playonlinux. Install a non-listed program. While installing tick the options install dotnet 4.0 libraries.
3. When the choose setup file to run dialog opens click cancel.
4. Go to Options. In the Playonlinux configuration choose on the left your virtual drive that you created during step 2.
5. Choose Miscellaneous tab on the top of the window, then Open virtual drive directory
6. Ubuntu file manager will pop-up. Open the drive_c directory. Create a new directory in the drive_c directory and extract the Ilspy binaries there.
7. Go to the Playonlinux configuration window and choose General tab. Click Make a new shortcut from this virtual drive. In the dialog choose Ilspy.exe.
8. Run your newly created shortcut.

You should see the ilspy window:
[image: Ilspy]

Comment: I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)

Comment: How do i install ilspy?

Comment: The answer is updated with detailed how to.